# Why does R give me a time series of row numbers instead of values?

Tags: r, time-series

### Why does R give me a time series of row numbers instead of values?

I load a CSV with a single column of values in the order I need them. I'm trying to make it a time series. Instead of giving me the values I've entered, R gives me the row number.

Here is what I get. If someone could help me understand what's happening and how I can get the time series of my values, I would be grateful.

Shown below, the actual list of values in the object "values".
The time series with a plain old ts() run on values.
The time series when I provide a start date and frequency.

```
> values
[1] 9976955.44  9362712.43  10012331.62 10068304.8  10532572.67 10195531.47 10324432.96 11208386.78
[9] 10700973.87 11068831.1  10176578.68 10188604.94 11380302.06 10204762.87 10668741.18 10897544.85
[17] 11521619.21 10323947.98 10778145.47 10454028.37 10455870.06 10382488.99 9987219.4   10260642.81
[25] 10848819.19 9732347.5   10203843.16 9869125.29  7542383.87  8569148.28  9890259.72  9440525.82 
[33] 9361047.7   9715566.45  8409379.61 
35 Levels: 10012331.62 10068304.8 10176578.68 10188604.94 10195531.47 10203843.16 ... 9987219.4

ts(values)
 Time Series:
Start = 1 
End = 35 
Frequency = 1 
[1] 34 28  1  2 14  5 10 21 16 20  3  4 22  7 15 19 23  9 17 12 13 11 35  8 18 31  6 32 24 26 33 29 27 30 25
attr(,"levels")
[1] 10012331.62  10068304.8 10176578.68 10188604.94 10195531.47 10203843.16 10204762.87 10260642.81
[9] 10323947.98 10324432.96 10382488.99 10454028.37 10455870.06 10532572.67 10668741.18 10700973.87
[17] 10778145.47 10848819.19 10897544.85  11068831.1 11208386.78 11380302.06 11521619.21  7542383.87
[25]  8409379.61  8569148.28   9361047.7  9362712.43  9440525.82  9715566.45   9732347.5  9869125.29
[33]  9890259.72  9976955.44   9987219.4

ts(values, start=c(2012, 1), frequency=12)
 Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec
2012  34  28   1   2  14   5  10  21  16  20   3   4
2013  22   7  15  19  23   9  17  12  13  11  35   8
2014  18  31   6  32  24  26  33  29  27  30  25
```

Comment: Convert factor `values` to numeric `as.numeric(levels(values))[values]`

Comment: That was it. Could you add that as an answer so I can credit you with it? Thanks so much for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `values` variable is a `factor` (usually used for categorical values).
Convert values to numeric before creating time series:

```
values <- as.numeric(levels(values))[values]
```